# Detecting OLED display refresh frequency using phototransistor

Tags: arduino, comparator, atmega328p, phototransistor, oled

I am trying to detect the refresh frequency of an OLED display driven by an SSD1309 display controller. During the refresh cycle, each row of a frame is charged and driven for 65 DCLKS in a sequential manner. After every row has been driven, the process immediately repeats from the first row to start the next frame. A DLCK is determined by the internal oscillator frequency divided by a programmable divide ratio.

For my test setup, I have mounted a TEMPT6000 ambient light sensor directly to the surface of the display and have turned on the pixel directly under the sensor. I am reading the sensor using the programmable analog comparator found on the ATmega328P microcontroller (Arduino Uno Rev3). I've set the positive side of the comparator to the bandgap reference voltage (1.1V) and the negative to the sensor output. The analog comparator interrupt is enabled and set to trigger on the rising edge of the comparator output.

First, I set the divide ratio to the maximum of 16 and drive all 64 rows of the display. Here is what it looks like when I plot the time between interrupts in microseconds.
[image]

This shows about 115,820 μs between interrupts, or about 8.6 Hz. I can confirm this is accurate from my direct observation. It's worth noting that the plot occasionally dips to only 304 μs between interrupts. I suspect this could be due to noise.

If I configure the display controller to only drive 16 of the 64 rows, I can speed up the refresh rate by a factor of 4. This yields a refresh rate of 34.4 Hz as expected. With a divide ratio of 4, I get another 4x increase to 137.8 Hz.

When I drop the divide ratio to 2, something peculiar happens.

[image]

You can see the time between interrupts hovers around 1120 μs, or about 892 Hz. Since this is much faster than the 275.6 Hz that I would expect, this seems to be incorrect. I also noticed the dips are a lot more consistent here.

Finally, a divide ratio of 1 (full speed) yields an identical plot.

There seems to be something special about this 1120 μs. When I hold the sensor up to the status LED on the Arduino, I also get an interrupt every 1120 μs. Here are a few of my theories in no particular order.

1. I am exceeding the interrupt rate of the ATmega328P.
2. I am exceeding the response time of the analog comparator on the ATmega328P.
3. I am exceeding the response time of the TEMPT6000 sensor.

Does anything I have outlined here point to one of these theories being more or less likely?